# Question about proof of Lamé's theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, euclidean-algorithm

I ran into a proof for Lamé's theorem that has confused me. The proof goes like this:

Prove: P(b): The number of recursive calls made by the Euclid-GCD algorithm when run with inputs $a ≥ b$ with $b<F_{k+1}$ is $<k$.

Basis step: the author chooses P(1) and P(2) for the base cases.

Inductive step: We will assume that $P(1) , ... , P(b − 1)$ holds for an arbitrary integer $b ≥ 3$ and then show that $P(b)$ holds.

Suppose $k$ is the smallest integer such that $b < F_{k+1}$. This means that $b ≥ F_k$. We break the analysis into the following two parts:

$a(mod b) < F_k$: In this case, after the first recursive call, the pair of numbers that is used for further recursive calls is $(b, a(mod b))$. Now since in this case, a $(mod b) < b$ and $a(mod b) < F_k$, using the induction hypothesis, we get that the number of further recursive calls is $< (k−1)$ and hence the total number of recursive calls is $< (k − 1) + 1 = k$.

$a(mod b) ≥ F_k$: In this case, the pair of numbers after the first recursive call is $(b,a (mod b))$. Let the pair after the second recursive call be $(a(mod b),d)$. Then, since $a(mod b) ≥ F_k$ and $b<F_{k+1}$, we have $d<b+1−a(modb)≤F_{k+1}−F_k = F_{k−1}$. Moreover,since $d<b$, we can apply the inductive hypothesis to conclude that the total number of recursive calls is $< (k − 2) + 2 = k$.

The above two cases shows that $P(b)$ holds. So, we conclude that $P(n)$ holds for all values of $n ≥ 1$

**I have a couple of questions about this proof:**

First, what is the use this statement in the proof: "This means that $b ≥ F_k$"?

Second, how does $d<b+1−a(modb)≤F_{k+1}−F_k = F_{k−1}$ follow from $a(mod b) ≥ F_k$ and $b<F_{k+1}$?

Comment: 1. Only if $b \ge F_k$, the two cases make sense. 2. at the start of second recursive call, we had ($b, a \ mod \ b$), where we assumed $b \ge a \ mod \ b$. The smallest value of $b$ is $a \ mod \ b$. So after second recursive call, we will have $d = 0$ which is less than $b + 1 - a \ mod \  b$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this geometric description of the Euclidean algorithm helpful in getting some intuition behind the proof.

https://nrich.maths.org/1357

Note that the Euclidean algorithm, *viewed in reverse*, creates a rectangular spiral.
The slowest-growing spiral is that in which the rectangles are Fibonacci numbers (because each new entry is the sum of the two prior entries, rather than a sum involving *higher multiples* of those prior entries.)

Thus when the algorithm is viewed going forward,  if you start with a pair of consecutive Fibonacci numbers, the Euclidean algorithm takes the most number of steps $k$ to reduce it them the gcd.